How can I prevent cancelling of pending requests on router navigation in Nuxt 3?
so I am working on an e-commerce product, where we have to download a lot of third part scripts for user journey tracking. To improve the performance of the application, we are loading these scripts very lazily i.e. they only start downloading after whole DOM content is loaded. This is causing problems, some of our users, while the one of the scripts is loading, navigates away, this loading request gets cancelled by the browser, and we don't get any subsequent event of that user journey. This is causing a significant data loss. Any one have any ideas how can I solve this problem?
